# Evolution of Cholesky factor given evolution of symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Given that the matrix $A$ is symmetric positive definite, and governed by the following set of ODEs for some matrix $B$:

$$\frac{dA}{dt}+AB+B^TA=0$$

is is possible to derive an evolution equation for the Cholesky factor $L$ where $A=LL^T$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dLL^\top}{dt} = L\frac{dL^\top}{dt} + \frac{dL}{dt}L^\top.$$

Comment: What is the connection with the differential equation given by the OP ?

Comment: This won't do the trick. It only tells you how the symmetric part of $\frac{dL}{dt}L^T$ evolves. It doesn't tell you everything about $\frac{dL}{dt}$.

Comment: I initially thought maybe this could be used to separate the ODEs into $L\frac{dL^T}{dt}+LL^TB=0$ and $\frac{dL}{dt}L^T+B^TLL^T=0$. These are essentially the same equation, $\frac{dL}{dt}+B^TL=0$. This would mean that the upper-triangle elements of $L$ turn non-zero over time, however.